# Implementation Legal for electronic Signature for consent in USA?

Tags: electronic-signature

I am working on a web application for disabled individuals who might need a consent form filled in by the responsible party for treatment in a medical center.

My idea is to have the clinician fill in the email addresses for responsible party and have a one-time link sent over. The responsible party gets the email and clicks on the link and views the document. Then they fill in their name and click consent, the link is removed and action is recorded. The clinician gets a confirmation and a web page to view the names of the parties consenting and time they have consented.

Is the above enough legally for the consent? Do we need more documentation to say that the third party has given their consent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In most states the intention for consent is sufficient to establish consent in court. Just make sure that it cant be modified afterwards. I'll try to find you a citation of this information somewhere.

Here you go, under general intent:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Signatures_in_Global_and_National_Commerce_Act

Your signature will most likely fall under "generic electronic signature" and not "secure electronic signature". Make sure you research some more and cover your butt. Think about what you will do if they say they never clicked on your link, or that they clicked it by accident, etc.

Comment: thanks. how do you make sure it can't be modified. Once it is recorded in db, technically anyone with db privileges can modify anything. I am not sure how it can be prevented.

Comment: Off the top of my head I know one of the ways they check for fraud is to see when the item was last modified. If you can show that there was no way for item to be modified inside the program, and can show a history of it being unmodifiable (for example on GitHub, and showing that the ability to modify was stripped out before the date signed). That might be enough. You might want to remove the ability to edit these documents after being signed, or some other arbitrary barrier. For example save to 2 databases, one that is readonly on your program, and one that can be edited by your doctors.

Comment: The bottom line is you want a paper trail. Anything that can show it hasn't been changed since being signed should be sufficient. You might want to do some research, but it shouldn't be too much of a headache. You just need some kind of evidence available on your side.

Comment: Since your patients are disabled and being assisted by a clinician, you could also have the clinician sign on the same document as a Witness to the signature. That should be sufficient. So if the client says they didn't sign but the clinician says they did and were a witness, the law suite wont fly. You may have to rethink your signing scheme a little to accommodate this, or however you choose to do it.

Comment: Make sure you do your own research to verify that any of these methods will work where you live.